# jQuery toggle меню

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь реализовать отображение дополнительного меню по клику на ссылку из основного меню. slideToggle отрабатывает, но нужен следующий функционал: при нажатии на ссылку из основного меню, снизу выезжает дополнительное меню. При повторном нажатии на эту же ссылку из основного меню, дополнительное меню сворачивается обратно. Если же дополнительное меню открыто и хочу кликнуть на другую ссылку из основного меню, то дополнительное меню должно свернуться и развернуться снова после нажатия на следующую ссылку.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.services__categories-list__item').click(function() {
    $('.services__search__categories-list__submenu').slideToggle(300);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services__categories-list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>
        <a class="services__categories-list__item" href="">УСЛУГА 1</a>
      </h3>
      <h3>
        <a class="services__categories-list__item" href="">УСЛУГА 2</a>
      </h3>
      <h3>
        <a class="services__categories-list__item" href="">УСЛУГА 3</a>
      </h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="services__search__categories-list__submenu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h4><a href="">Подкатегории услуг</a></h4>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы точно понимаете, как работают ссылки ? При нажатие на ссылку пользователя пербрасывает на новую страницу и код его `html` страници заменяеться на новый. - Это я к тому, что эффект перехода по нажатию на ссылку (а не её имитацию) происходить не будет, пользователь покинет текущую страницу и получит новый контент... Если у вас на SPA (в чём я сильно сомниваюсь)

Comment: причем здесь работа ссылок? и не обязательно ссылка подразумевает переход на другую страницу. и почему вы сомневаетесь что это SPA? )

Comment: `и почему вы сомневаетесь что это SPA?` -- наверное потому что вопрос о toggle меню на jQuery.

Comment: Ещё раз, по пунктам. 1) Ссылка предназначена для того что б перенаправить пользователя на новую страницу. Её внешний вид не важен, если элемент у вас выполняет что-то другое, это может быть заменено любым другим элементом к примеру `<button>` 2) то что вы хотите получить согласно вашего описание \ Если же дополнительное меню открыто и хочу кликнуть на другую ссылку из основного меню, то дополнительное меню должно свернуться\ это противопоставляеться пункту 1. При нажатию на ссылку идет запрос на сервер с последуйщей отрисовкой новой страницы или её части. Пользователь покидает текущую страницу

Comment: ссылка не всегда подразумевает переход на новую страницу! могут быть якорные ссылки, это только один пример. к сожалению, мне нужна реализация скрипта, логику которого я описал выше, а не обсуждение сущности ссылок

Answer (score 0):

Вот так виглядит ваш пример в нормальном мире.

```js
const submenu = $(".submenu");

$(".service_item").on("click", function() {
  const currentSub = $(this).closest("li").find(".submenu");
  if (currentSub.is(":visible")) {
    return;
  }

  submenu.slideUp(200);
  currentSub.slideDown(200);
})
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services__categories-list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button class="service_item">УСЛУГА 1</button>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Подкатегории услуг</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="service_item">УСЛУГА 2</button>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">Подкатегории услуг</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Подкатегории услуг</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Подкатегории услуг</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="services_item" href="">УСЛУГА 3</a>></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, конечно, за участие в решение моего вопроса, но мне нужно решение конкретно для моей верстки и конкретно моего случая, а не как вы говорите "в нормальном виде". но все равно спасибо